# TextRange.select() doesn't work with speaker note shape

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Consider I have one slide with a sentence "This is a beautiful world." written in it.
I want to do a selection on the part of the text say "This"
I write the following code but it throws exception on Google server for select() operation.

```
function select() {
  var notesPage = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getNotesPage();
  var textRange = notesPage.getSpeakerNotesShape().getText();
  textRange.getRange(0, 4).select();
}

function replace() {
  var notesPage = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getNotesPage();
  var textRange = notesPage.getSpeakerNotesShape().getText();
  textRange.getRange(0, 4).setText('newText');
}
```

The select function fails, the replace function works.
Could anyone help me making a selection inside a speaker note shape?

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail information of ``When I perform a select on textrange on notes page it fails``? In your situation, you did as follows? 1. Select a text in the speaker note. 2. Run the script. By the way, what is ``selection.getTextRange().selecenter code heret();``?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for that. It's selection.getTextRange().select();

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have one more question. 1. In your situation, you did as follows? 1. Select a text in the speaker note. 2. Run the script. If you do this flow, I think that the text data in the speaker note can be retrieved. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike My addon wants to modify text in speaker notes and highlight the text that was modified. 

1. I select text from speaker note.
2. Run script which retrieves the text. (TextRange) . 
3. then modifies the text using TextRange.setText('new text');
4. then selects the new text TextRange.select()

My problem is this works perfectly for shapes in slide but not for speaker notes.

Comment: It seems that your latest comment is different from your initial question. Can you update your question? It will help users think of your updated question.

Comment: @Tanaike I have edited the question, I hope its more simple to understand now

Comment: Thank you for updating it. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the text at the speaker notes cannot be selected by the script yet. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the clarification. That's pity of Google Slides, looks like a half baked cookie. The same situation exists with Group shapes, wordArt too.